# No more sound output in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: upgrade, sound, updates

On Dell Latitude E5440 I run Ubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit LTS. As far as I am concerned after getting some upgrades I am getting no sound output in Ubuntu although it works in Windows on the same machine. How can I remedy this situation?

**Additional Info:** I tried reinstalling Alsa and Pulse Audio as described in this [link](http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/). However, this did not resolve the problem I am facing. The output of `aplay -l` is as follows:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC292 Analog [ALC292 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**LAST EDIT**: The problem was resolved by running the following command(also note that the setting in `/etc/default/speech-dispatcher` is set to `no`):

`sudo aptitude --purge reinstall linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils linux-image-uname -r linux-ubuntu-modules-uname -r libasound2`

Screenshots of settings:

[image]

Comment: This could be simple or complex. It's hard to tell given the limited information you've provided. Please [edit] your question and include what you've tried, and any results you got (good or bad). Once you've done so, drop a comment which includes @ElderGeek and I'll take another look. Some useful information would be volume settings shown in system settings->sound, whether or not you have pulse audio installed, and etc......

Comment: @ElderGeek I included some more information.

Comment: What output are you trying to use? 1/8" jack or HDMI?

Comment: @ElderGeek Just speakers but I have not tried with earphones they might work.

Comment: Is anything showing up as muted ("MM") in `alsamixer` ?

Comment: @ElderGeek Everything is on, nothing is muted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22737/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-vesnog).

Comment: Possible work-around. From the grub boot menu, choose Ubuntu advanced options and then boot with the previous kernel. It's possible something got dropped in the latest kernel update that is causing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just you! The update broke my sound too, Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (64-bit), Dell Optiplex 760. But I got it fixed.

Try these menus: System Tools ... Preferences ... Sound, and make sure your sound isn't muted or turned all the way down. That's what seemed to work for me.

The "speaker-test" utility worked for me (e.g., it could produce sound), so then I tried the "sound recorder" accessory, which let me go to the sound preferences. What did not work: the AlsaMixer utility that runs in a terminal window. Everything looked great ... and I had no sound.

Best wishes, and let us know how this goes for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, please see the edit I am just about to make. The problem is resolved but in a more complex way.